# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Please help - getting below error when trying to run:

```
**Compiler message:
/C:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_sticky_header-0.3.4/lib/src/widgets/sticky_header_layout_builder.dart:147:16: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
      context: context);
               ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**
```

when running `flutter run -v` within terminal I get the following errors:

```
C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest>flutter run -v
[  +34 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +95 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 0b8abb4724aa590dd0f429683339b1e045a1594d
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[  +81 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.8-0-g0b8abb472
[  +12 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +63 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +50 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +140 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +69 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[ +185 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +30 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:sdk_gphone_x86 device:generic_x86_arm transport_id:2
[  +21 ms] C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[ +114 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +11 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +9 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +97 ms] Found plugin cloud_firestore at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\
[  +20 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.2.5+1\
[  +20 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\git\plugins-0a9d0c576a69f9b5d464ad811600e50a7b687911\packages\google_maps_flutter\
[  +26 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.5.1\
[  +38 ms] Found plugin sqflite at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-1.2.0\
[  +89 ms] Found plugin cloud_firestore at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3\
[   +8 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.2.5+1\
[  +14 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\git\plugins-0a9d0c576a69f9b5d464ad811600e50a7b687911\packages\google_maps_flutter\
[  +17 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.5.1\
[  +19 ms] Found plugin sqflite at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sqflite-1.2.0\
[  +82 ms] Generating C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +38 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +50 ms] Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
[  +25 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
[  +17 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +87 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[   +1 ms] --------- beginning of main
           03-06 00:29:48.113 E/netmgr  ( 2114): Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
[  +14 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[   +3 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 logcat -v time -T 03-06 00:29:48.113
[  +88 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 29.0.6-6198805
           Installed as C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +6 ms] executing: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +90 ms] Building APK
[  +26 ms] [!] Your app isn't using AndroidX.
[   +1 ms]     To avoid potential build failures, you can quickly migrate your app by following the steps on .
[  +20 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +6 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[  +15 ms] Using gradle from C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\android\gradlew.bat.
[  +20 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +177 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_212-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
[   +6 ms] executing: [C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\android\] C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget=C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root -Ptarget-platform=android-x86 assembleDebug
[+5306 ms] :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[   +1 ms] [  +82 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +110 ms] [ +141 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] [   +2 ms] 0b8abb4724aa590dd0f429683339b1e045a1594d
[   +1 ms] [        ] executing: [C:\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[  +80 ms] [  +90 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +1 ms] [        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.8-0-g0b8abb472
[   +9 ms] [  +15 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +77 ms] [  +72 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] [        ] origin/stable
[        ] [        ] executing: [C:\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +78 ms] [  +69 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +7 ms] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +135 ms] [ +156 ms] executing: [C:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +83 ms] [  +79 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] [        ] stable
[  +53 ms] [  +47 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [   +7 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +240 ms] [ +254 ms] Initializing file store
[  +53 ms] [  +50 ms] Done initializing file store
[+3210 ms] [+3208 ms] kernel_snapshot: Starting due to {}
[  +55 ms] [  +45 ms] C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe C:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --target=flutter -Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts
--track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\.packages --output-dill
C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\.dart_tool\flutter_build\9e8e8d46a18ccb5b75fbdc16ee578c68\app.dill --depfile
C:\allflutterprojects\rapidinhotest\.dart_tool\flutter_build\9e8e8d46a18ccb5b75fbdc16ee578c68\kernel_snapshot.d package:rapidinho/main.dart
[+10351 ms] [+10361 ms]
[   +3 ms]             Compiler message:
[   +1 ms] [   +3 ms] /C:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_sticky_header-0.3.4/lib/src/widgets/sticky_header_layout_builder.dart:147:16:
Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
[   +6 ms] [        ]  - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
[   +2 ms] [        ]       context: context);
[   +1 ms] [        ]                ^
[+4886 ms] [+4894 ms] Persisting file store
[  +54 ms] [  +57 ms] Done persisting file store
[   +1 ms] [   +2 ms] Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
[  +35 ms] [  +24 ms] "flutter assemble" took 19,035ms.
[   +1 ms] build failed.
[   +4 ms] #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
[   +2 ms] #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:183:7)
[   +1 ms] <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms] #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:615:18)
[   +1 ms] <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms] #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:515:33)
[   +3 ms] <asynchronous suspension>
[   +5 ms] #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:146:29)
[   +1 ms] #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
[   +1 ms] #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
[   +1 ms] #7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
[   +1 ms] #8      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
[   +1 ms] #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:145:18)
[   +1 ms] #10     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:505:20)
[   +1 ms] #11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
[   +1 ms] #12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:413:21)
[   +1 ms] <asynchronous suspension>
[   +2 ms] #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:146:29)
[   +1 ms] #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
[   +1 ms] #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
[   +1 ms] #16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
[        ] #17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
[   +1 ms] #18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:145:18)
[   +1 ms] #19     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:364:19)
[        ] #20     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
[   +1 ms] #21     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
[   +2 ms] #22     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
[   +1 ms] #23     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:250:18)
[   +2 ms] #24     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:22)
[   +2 ms] #25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
[   +1 ms] #26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
[        ] #27     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
[        ] #28     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1502:12)
[   +1 ms] #29     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61:18)
[   +1 ms] <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms] #30     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:146:29)
[   +1 ms] #31     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
[   +1 ms] #32     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
[   +1 ms] #33     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
[   +5 ms] #34     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
[   +2 ms] #35     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:145:18)
[   +1 ms] #36     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:64:24)
[   +1 ms] #37     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:10)
[   +1 ms] #38     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:65:9)
[   +1 ms] #39     main (file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
[   +1 ms] #40     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:32)
[   +1 ms] #41     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
[  +46 ms] :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[   +4 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * Where:
[   +1 ms] Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780
[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[   +1 ms] > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[   +1 ms] * Try:
[   +1 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +1 ms] BUILD FAILED in 24s
[   +1 ms] 1 actionable task: 1 executed
[ +600 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 25.8s)
[  +17 ms] "flutter run" took 27,236ms.
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:387:7)
#2      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:32:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:290:13)
#11     _DefaultProcessUtils.stream (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart)
#12     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#15     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#17     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#18     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#19     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:554:7)
#20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#22     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#23     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#26     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#27     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:175:5)
```

Comment: Are you using an older version (0.3.4)? Current is 0.4.2. Please show your `pubspec.yaml` dependencies.

Comment: Thank you yes that is solved, but now i have different problem: 'Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (16.0.1) and runtime (17.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution'